# シェルスクリプトでループの最後を判定する

Tags: linux, shellscript, sh

以下のようにフォルダ内のファイル名を5秒おきに列挙するシェルがあります。

```
for file in `ls /home/test/`; do
    echo "${file}"
    sleep 5
done
```

最後のファイル名を表示した後は5秒待機する必要がないので、ループの最後だけは `sleep 5` を実行したくないのですが、どのように記述すれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: 本題とは関係ありませんが、`ls` の出力を使ってループするとファイル名にスペースが含まれているときに誤作動する場合があります。代わりに、ファイルごとに分けてくれるよう[ワイルドカードを使う方法](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20796200/5989200)や、`find` コマンドの `-exec` オプションを使う方法が知られています。

Comment: 逆に考えてみてはどうでしょう。最初のファイル以外では、ファイル名を表示する前に sleep する、と。`i=0;for file in /home/test/*; do { [ $i -eq 0 ] && i=1 || sleep 5; }; echo "${file}"; done`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

絡め手ですが、echoの評価前に5秒スリープするようにします。
最初の1回はスリープしないようにしておけば、最後の1個の終了後
ループを抜けて終わります。

```
count=0
for file in `ls .`; do
  #最初の1回はスリープしない。
  if [ $count -ne  0 ]; then
    sleep 5
  fi
  echo ${file}
  ((count++ ))
done
```

Comment: あ、かぶった。。。申し訳ございません。

Comment: せっかくなので、別解。最初のコメントにnekketsuuuさんが書かれているように、find使う方法もあります。
`find <path> -type f -exec echo {} \; -exec sleep 5 \;`
これだと、最初の1回も5秒またされますので、別途判定ロジックが必要です。ご参考まで

Comment: 被ること自体はそこまで気になさることではないと思います ;-)

Comment: 空白が入ったファイル名のことも考えると、``for file in `ls .`; do`` より `for file in ./* ; do` の方が良いです。

Comment: なるほど。確かに。最初のコメントで*を使う方法とあったのですが、そういうことだったのですね。理解しました。勉強になります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: `if`から`fi`の部分を`{ test "${flag:-0}" -eq 1 && sleep 5; } || flag=1`とすると`((count++ ))`しなくてもよくなりそうです。

Answer (score 4):

@伽語蓮弥 さんの回答をベースに、手元で動くようにしたのが次です。 POSIX compliant, スペース入りファイル名称にも対応しています。また、ファイル名称が `hoge\nfuga` のような、 echo によって特殊処理されるような名称であった場合にもそのまま出力するために、 printf を用いています。

#### test.sh

```
ls_with_sleep() {
    set -- *
    while test $# -gt 0; do
        printf '%s\n' "$1"
        shift
        test $# -eq 0 || {
            echo sleeping...
            sleep 1
        }
    done
}

ls_with_sleep
```

#### 実行結果

```
 % ls -1
foo
hoge fuga
hoge\nfuga
test.sh
 % ./test.sh 
foo
sleeping...
hoge fuga
sleeping...
hoge\nfuga
sleeping...
test.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash 特有の機能を使って良ければ、配列を使って書けます。

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/path/to/target/directory"
files=("$dir/"*)
lastIndex=$((${#files[*]} - 1))

for i in $(seq 0 $((lastIndex - 1)))
do
    echo "${files[$i]}"
    sleep 5
done
echo "${files[$lastIndex]}"
```

POSIX shell 限定であれば、一旦ファイルの数を数えて、その後最後のファイルかどうかを判定する方法を思いつきました。スクリプトの実行中にファイルの数が変わりうるときには誤作動するのでご注意ください。

```
#!/bin/sh

dir="/path/to/target/directory"

# ファイルの数をカウント
lastIndex=0
for name in "$dir/"*
do
    lastIndex=$((lastIndex + 1))
done

# 出力
i=1
for name in "$dir/"*
do
    echo "$name"
    if [ "$i" -lt "$lastIndex" ]
    then
        sleep 5
    fi
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

これらの方法は愚直ですが、それぞれのファイルに対して実行したいコマンドが遅いときでも使えます。コマンドの実行前に `sleep` を実行する方法は、`echo` のようにコマンドの実行時間が充分短い場合には有効ですが、実行時間が長い場合には使えません。

Comment: 手元の環境だと`lastIndex="$(locate --count --regexp "$dir/[^\]\+$")"`でも同様のカウントをすることができましたが、標準の`ls`の出力だと`.bashrc`だとか`.profile`みたいなファイル名は出力されないのでそれらを除外する必要があるように思いました。

Comment: @伽語蓮弥 さん、なるほど、`locate` コマンドを使うのは初めて知りました。一方、`locate` には `updatedb` が用意してくれるデータベースが必要なので、`updatedb.conf` で除外されているディレクトリで作業するときには使えないことに気づきました（私が `/tmp` で作業していて、私の環境では `/tmp` は除外されていました）。

Comment: ああ、言われてみれば除外されるディレクトリがあるんでした。いつもテスト環境は~/tmp/に作っているのでその点は意識の外でした。

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "/home/test/" && set -- *
while test "${#@}" -gt 0; do
    { test "${flag:-0}" -eq 1 && sleep 5; } || flag=1
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

先に結果を変数に格納しておいて、順次表示する形です。

Comment: また、 #@ の変数は、自分は見たことないのですが、これは何を表わす変数なのでしょうか。。?

Comment: @Yuki Inoue globの挙動を勘違いしていました。${#@}は$@に格納されている文字列の長さです。${#1}でもいいのだと思うのですが全体の長さを使うほうが個人的には好みでしたので。

Answer (score 2):

```
LAST="`ls |tail -1`"
ls | while read i ;do
  echo $i
  if [ "$i" = "$LAST" ];then
    break
  fi
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: `ls` が出力する最後のファイル名に改行が含まれていると誤動作します。`-g` オプションか `-b` オプションを使うと回避できそうです。たとえば `ls -1b | tail -n 1` など。

Answer (score 2):

ループの中(`do`)ではなく評価の方(`while`)にやりたいことを持っていけばシンプルに書けると思います。

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- /home/test/*
while
    [ -e "$1" ] && basename "$1"
    shift
    [ $# -gt 0 ]
do sleep 5; done
```

Answer (score 1):

別解です。
ループでCSVの行を作成するとき、行の最後に`,`を付けたくないときの書き方の応用です。

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=
for file in `ls /home/test/`; do
    ${cmd}
    cmd="sleep 5"
    echo "${file}"
done
```

Comment: `${cmd:-}`にすれば`for`ループに入る前の`cmd=`が必要なくなると思います。それと質問へのコメントにあるように`ls`するよりもglobを使うほうが好ましいようです。

Comment: 伽語蓮弥さん、コメントありがとうございます。実は`for`ループに入る前の`cmd=`は、後から編集で追加しました。このスクリプトで問題となることはありませんが、cmdに何かが入っていて大丈夫なようにしたかったからです。`glob`を使うと「too many file」のエラーに悩まされることが多かったので、使わないことが習慣になっていたようです。今試してみましたが、10.000ファイルではエラーになりませんでした。使用したshは`GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`です。※`glob`という言葉は初めて知りました。